# Why does colab disconnect?

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I am trying to load my dataset. I have been using colab's TPU for many times,but the colab gets disconnected every time. I have tried all the methods to keep it connected, still it doesn't work. I have been training for more than 10 hours and still the colab gets disconnected. What do I do??

Answer (score 0):

There could be many possibilities why your session is crashing.

1. There is a time limit for the free tier in Google Colab. If your execution gets over the time, it disconnects.
2. Also check the RAM usage, if that exceeds the session will crash.
3. The storage limits might exceed.

Run and keep an eye on these factors. And try to optimise the code or use aws for training.

Answer (score 0):

As @HarshitRuwali mentioned there are several reasons for why this would happen.

Regarding the question "what do I do?" - you can purchase a subscription for [Colab Pro](https://colab.research.google.com/signup), which eliminates/relaxes different limitations, including the time limit.

Comment: Yeah but last time I checked Colab Pro was not available for all the regions, I dont know why. But you can always use aws.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know there was a geo limit... then yes indeed you could use aws, gcp, or azure, although it's not quite the same...